# .htaccess redirect domain.com to www.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess

I am looking for a .htaccess redirect such that all request that come in for mydomain.com are redirected to www.mydomain.com. It is important tho that any sub domain request is not affected i.e. request for sub.domain.com should not be redirected.

If found this which seems to do the opposite of what I want:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.purchase\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://purchase.DOMAIN_NAME/$1 [L,R]
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Regards
Gabriel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: Thanks ... I have this already in my .htaccess <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
Where should I place the code you provided?

Comment: place it between "RewriteEngine on" and your first rewriterule.

Comment: I am afraid it causing problem to my cakephp installation :S

Comment: These worked for me: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^aidengine.net$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.aidengine.net/$1